# My hair particle are pointing upwards and downwards, how do I make it point only upwards?

Tags: particles

I am trying to add sprinkles to my doughnut, but I cannot get my hair particles to face upwards alone, Mine faces both upwards and downwards.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone who knows how to fix this can explain how it is done.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly isn't working? A few details would help. Some things to try: Vertex groups, separating objects, and hair combing to erase particles

Comment: I want the hair particles to face upwards.

Comment: I don't think you understand what the issue is. The issue is the particles are being emitted from the bottom of the mesh. Making them face the other way will just make them be inside the mesh in the same spot

Comment: So how do I emit the particles from the top of the mesh?

Comment: Did you research and try what I suggested? We have no idea what you have tried, so we can't help you. You need to edit your question and add some more details

Answer (score 1):

[image]
If I understand your question properly, this is what you are trying to achieve. If yes then follow these steps:

Select the top faces and assign them to a vertex
group like this:
[image]

Then in the particles tab go to vertex group > density option > select the vertex you made (default in the name of group)

Comment: i think it is important you mention the term 'weight paint'

Comment: Weight painting is a way of defining vertex groups, it is not related to this method of assigning vertices to a vertex group